# Favorites Links per user

Tags: 2013

I want to create a site collection with a list of links and render them as Titles as shown here: http://alinimer.com/2013/02/09/oob-creating-your-own-custom-tiles-in-sharepoint-2013/

Because we have about 50 internal applications, every person uses a different set of applications, it would be more interesting if it renders only the ones you mark as Favorites for example.

I can create a favorite boolean, but of course becuase its a list, the value its the same for everyone.

I wonder, how would you solve this? that every person can only see the ones they mark as favorites?

Thanks

Comment: hi can you post a details answer of the solution you used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 1 list of links to your internal apps.

Create a second list with a lookup to the first list.  Change the settings so users can only see and edit their own items.

You can now maintain the options available in one place and can create a view on the second list where users only see the items they are interested in.

Even though users can only see their own items, it is worth adding a filter where Created By = [Me] to ensure site collection admins also only see their own.

Comment: Hi am in need of the same solution,By creating a second list you mean create a second promoted link add-in? ...can you explain how use that lookup